# Jira - how can I set that Client should only be able to see parent, but not any of the sub-tasks?

Tags: jira

I want to use Jira for Client acting purposes. I plan the project in Jira, but keep it high level, eg.: Design, Development, QA. These should be visible to the Client. When we move into development I want my devs to create the actual tickets they need, but the Client should not see them. How do I set this up? Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like clients should only have insight into user-stories and the `Plan` view, while the devs will populate the user stories with actual tasks in the `Work` view..... Maybe just make a shared Client filter available to all `client` users?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about a specific programming problem.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a Issue Security Scheme but the harder part is setting the right security level on a issue according to the issue type. Perhaps a custom post function would be the way to go.